# Copy value to another column only if substring (or symbol) occurs in particular column, else leave another column unchanged DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe I have:

```
cost      total     
null      $519
null      $78
xx24
($1500)   
          $51
0.00    
($924)
$33
          $78
```

Desired:

```
cost      total     
null      $519
null      $78
xx24
($1500)   $1500
          $51
0.00    
($924)    $924
$33       $33
          $78
```

I tried defining method and using **apply()** but that would also replace already existing values in **'total'**.
I can get 'true/false' values into new column but that just doesn't seem like the right way.

Comment: what substring occurs?

Comment: it can be '$'..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract values between `()` but only for rows with `$` selected by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask = df['cost'].str.contains('$', na=False, regex=False)

df['total'] = df['total'].mask(mask, df['cost'].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)" , expand=False))

#another solution from copy and strip () 
#df['total'] = df['total'].mask(mask, df['cost'].str.strip('()'))
print (df)
      cost  total
0      NaN   $519
1      NaN    $78
2     xx24    NaN
3  ($1500)  $1500
4      NaN    $51
5     0.00    NaN
6   ($924)   $924
7      NaN    $78
```

Or if possible replace missing values from `total` by values extracted from `()` use:

```
df['total'] = df['total'].fillna(df['cost'].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)" , expand=False))
print (df)
      cost  total
0      NaN   $519
1      NaN    $78
2     xx24    NaN
3  ($1500)  $1500
4      NaN    $51
5     0.00    NaN
6   ($924)   $924
7      NaN    $78
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using numpy.where()

```
df['total'] = np.where(df.cost.apply(lambda x:not pd.isnull(x) and '$' in x),
                  df.cost,
                  df.total)
df['total'] = df.total.apply(lambda x:x.replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))
```